# Memory leak when I select uwp listbox item frequently

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, listbox, uwp

I create a ListBox and register it's `SelectedChanged` event. But I don't do anything in event handler.
And I write a Ui automation test,it can select listbox's item in turn frequently.
(There are only five items in listbox);

When the test is running.I watch the app's private memory.It increased.

But when the test is over.The private memory is hold and doesn't been collect.
Even if I use memory profiler in Visual Studio force to `GC.Collect()`.

So I think it makes memory leak.

Could you help me ? Thanks.

Here is the demo project link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhlJbMNnQl72uaB1f86G-a2lEdMd3A

Comment: Do you have any screenshot from a memory profiler like [this](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) one?

Comment: I used VisualStudio Performance Profiler to watch memory ,the memory increased .When the ui test is finished.Memory didn't get lower.

Comment: Could you please also provide your reports. I tested your project on my side seems like I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: my test is base on WinAppDriver.exe(v0.3)，if you test by manual，the memory leak effect is not clear.Thanks.